# Show images inside a pdf created with Gloogle Apps Script Blob

Tags: image, pdf, google-apps-script, blob

I am creating PDF files using blobs in Google Apps Script from a HTML code, but the problem is that HTML code has an image (referenced by "http") but the created pdf can't show it.

This is my code

```
function createBlobPDF(myMessage,myTitle){
var blobHTML = Utilities.newBlob(myMessage, "text/html", myTitle+ ".html");
var myPDF = blobHTML.getAs("application/pdf");
return myPDF;
}
```

Any solution? thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the images in HTML are loaded from URLs, the converted PDF file doesn't include the images. If you want to include the images in the converted PDF file, please put the images to HTML as base64 data.

In order to confirm this situation, please see the following sample script. This sample script puts an image as URL and base64 data. The result is displayed them to a dialog and created a PDF file.

When you use this script, please copy and paste to the script editor of Spreadsheet.

#### Sample script :

```
function myFunction() {
  // image
  var url = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a";
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  var b64 = blob.getContentType() + ';base64,'+ Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes());
  var html = "URL<img src=\"" + url + "\">Base64<img src=\"data:" + b64 + "\">";
  var h = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);

  // Open dialog with the images.
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(h.setWidth(500).setHeight(200), 'Sample');

  // Create from HTML to PDF file.
  DriveApp.createFile(h.getAs("application/pdf").setName("text.pdf"));
}
```

#### Result of dialog :

Both images can be seen.

[image]

#### Result of PDF file :

Only the image of base64 can be seen.

[image]

#### Note :

- This is a simple script. So please modify this to your environment.

#### References :

- [How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: @flxcr07 Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

I tested converting html to pdf with image content. It works but in the bottom of a box, the color does not work! How to make the color to appear in the background of a box?

I wanted to show you my little treatment as an example "<>" but it doesn't work because there is no window for code.gs . Shame...
In short, see the final result in pdf, attached

before clicking on the "validate" button, the screen is displayed, see the screenshot below. this is where you "capture" the HTML presentation and then run to convert HTML to PDF.

[image]

after clicking on "validate", here is the result, see below :
[image]

normally, I would like to have the same result between screen and PDF.
Then, how to do it ?